# multiplicative inverses in modular arithmetic - breaking up a modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be distinct primes. Is it always true that the solution of the simultaneous congruence
$$ax \equiv 1 \mod{p_1}$$
$$ax \equiv 1 \mod{p_2}$$
is a solution to $ax \equiv 1 \mod{p_1p_2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes. If $p_1 \mid (aX-1)$ and $p_2 \mid (aX-1)$ then $p_1 p_2=lcm(p_1,p_2) \mid (aX-1)$.

Comment: I think that the greatest common divisor of two primes is 1, not p1*p2. Did you mean LCM?

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct! I am going to edit my answer.